# How to assign permission to access only one particular store in magento?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, e-commerce

I am working on magento 1.8ver .I have created some multiple websites/stores in this.Now I want to create a user and assign permission to access only one particular websites/store in magento. how can i do this ?

Actually, I have created a user and assign custom role for this and it is working fine but there is a option in system->configuration "current configuration scope".In this there are a option "default config" 
Please see the attached image for this.[image: admin system configuration]

If I change any setting with default config then it reflect on main store.So I want to remove default config from this drop down. So login user in this store can only change own store not others.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Magento do not have this feature, however there is paid module http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_advanced_permissions.html

Comment: Yes, For this I am using following extension :- http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-permissions-with-multi-vendor.html